# How to get sessions to function properly in a cross domain?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am using **MEAN** stack. It is letting me access the backend resources like finding data and deleting them from the frontend, but what I find confusing is when I visit path /blog on port 4200(angular), it still saves the session in the db, but it still won't let me visit the home page on the browser. And when I visit path /blog on port 3000(server), it saves the session, then giving access to the home page on the browser.

```
router.route("/blog").get((req, res) => {
    req.session.user = 1; // SESSION
});
```

### Edit

Cors seems to be an issue you guys are bringing up, but I already had it installed. It still does not work even though cors was already installed, the same issue still applies.

Comment: Are you getting any CORS error?

Comment: I am not getting any cors error. I actualy have localhost:4200 as the origin, but no errors.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: You may also want to check that `data["loggedIn"]` is actually a boolean and not string -- `"false" !== false`.

Comment: I am using angular 8.

Comment: This is a cors problem, you are trying to access another domain from 4200 this will be auto rejected. Install cors module on the backend and it will all be fine.

Comment: Have you confirmed it is loaded properly? `console.log(cors)` somewhere. Otherwise try to remove the argument `{  
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
    credentials: true
}`

Comment: @Michelangelo when I ran console.log(cors) I got [Function: middlewareWrapper]

Comment: I have found that proxy works.